# TypeError: Cannot read property 'basename' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'basename' of undefined`

when assigning the variable.

```
var basename = path.basename(module.filename);
```

but when I console log the value it displays the file.

```
console.log(path.basename(module.filename)) => server.js
```

Comment: `path` is clearly undefined at the time that code is being run. With more context we could say what's wrong that's causing it to be undefined, but just those lines are fine.

Comment: Well it's part of node. https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/path/

Comment: @StephenRomero you have to require it with `const path=require("path");`

Comment: sighhhhh. I just saw that.

Comment: @StephenRomero weird how node.js includes somethings like `util` by default and others have to be explicitly require'd

Comment: I actually had it imported, but it was initialized after the basename variable. It's also weird that it didn't give me the error of path being undefined.

Comment: @StephenRomero most likely because you're declaring things with `var` - leads to easy errors like that since it hoists the declaration to the top, using `const` for required modules is more ideal or just `let` is fine too